# Capturar una etiqueta HTML con JQuery en String

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Necesito capturar una etiqueta de HTML en String para manejarla dentro de una variable en JQuery, no logro capturarla, añado el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

```js
$("svg g, svg g g").each(function() {
  caseElement = $(this).children();
  console.log(caseElement);


  switch (caseElement) {
    case 'path':
      colorFill = $(this).attr('fill');
      if (colorFill !== undefined || colorFill !== 'none') {
        $(this).css('fill', 'red');
      }
      break;
    case 'prototype':
      alert('prototype Wins!');
      break;
    case 'mootools':
      alert('mootools Wins!');
      break;
    case 'dojo':
      alert('dojo Wins!');
      break;
    default:
      alert('Nobody Wins!');
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg>
<g>
<path fill="#B1C91E" d="M127.6,0c-5.4,0-9.7,4.4"></path>
                  </g>
                </svg>
```

Lo que necesitaría en este caso es capturar la etiqueta `path` en String y es lo que no logro hacer.

Comment: Agrega el código que has intentado, no podemos ayudarte y tu explicación es muy vaga.

Comment: Misma recomendación, necesitamos que pongas el código que llevar para, en base a el, poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Listo, estaba ajustando el código por que era bastante largo.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos puedes realizar algo como esto:

```js
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
  return jQuery('<div />').append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};
contenido = $('svg').outerHTML();

console.log(contenido);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <g>
    <path fill="#B1C91E" d="M127.6,0c-5.4,0-9.7,4.4"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Lo que se hace es crear una función esta es encargada de clonar tu etiqueta/tag svg a un div temporal, acto seguido obtenemos el contenido del mismo invocando a la función **outerHTML** y por consola nos muestra todo el tag/etiqueta.

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 0):

No se si sea lo que buscas pero la manera de obtener el texto de las etiquetas html es con el metodo `html()`, de igual manera sirve para asignar un valor.

```
<p id="titulo">Este es mi titulo</p>
<p id="valor"></p>
<script>
  var titulo = $("#titulo").html();
  $("#valor").html(titulo);
  alert(titulo);
</script>
```

Espero te sirva, y para la próxima por favor agrega mas información y si puedes un poco de código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya dispuse mas información, lo que sucede es que no necesito el contenido del p como tal sino la etiqueta como tal en string.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es acceder a la propiedad `nodeName` del índice 0 del hijo que estás capturando para el elemento, esto te devolverá el nombre de la etiqueta como tal para poder compararla en el `switch`.

```js
$("svg g, svg g g").each(function() {
  caseElement = $(this).children()[0].nodeName;
  console.log(caseElement);

  switch (caseElement) {
    case 'path':
      colorFill = $(this).attr('fill');
      if (colorFill !== undefined || colorFill !== 'none') {
        $(this).css('fill', 'red');
      }
      break;
    case 'prototype':
      alert('prototype Wins!');
      break;
    case 'mootools':
      alert('mootools Wins!');
      break;
    case 'dojo':
      alert('dojo Wins!');
      break;
    default:
      alert('Nobody Wins!');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg>
<g>
<path fill="#B1C91E" d="M127.6,0c-5.4,0-9.7,4.4"></path>
                  </g>
                </svg>
```